# Dismissing MFMailComposeViewController causes upward shift

Tags: ios, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've ran into an issue when dismissing the MFMailComposeViewController and returning to a shifted screen in iOS7. The method below has worked on iOS6 without shifting the screen upwards of about 25-30. Altering my`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]` to using auto resize isn't fixing my issue as suggested in another question of downward shifting.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)loadView {

    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"iShift"] autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *mail = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(sendMail)] autorelease];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = mail;
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
 [self.view addSubview:navBar];


}


- (void)sendMail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *compose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
compose.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@gmail.com", nil];
[compose setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[compose setSubject:@"Test Email"];
[compose setMessageBody:@"Device: \niOS Version: \nProblem: \n\nSuggestions: \n" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:compose animated:YES];

}

[compose release];

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue in what seems to be pretty dirty by changing `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]`  to  `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]` and padding the navbar position by 20pts resulting in the following code. If someone can point out a problem with this I'm open to suggestions. (With a tableview it's y position is also padded by 20pts)

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)loadView {

self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"iShift"] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *mail = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(sendMail)] autorelease];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = mail;
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];


}


- (void)sendMail {

MFMailComposeViewController *compose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
compose.mailComposeDelegate = self;

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample@gmail.com", nil];
[compose setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[compose setSubject:@"Test Email"];
[compose setMessageBody:@"Device: \niOS Version: \nProblem: \n\nSuggestions: \n" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:compose animated:YES];

}

[compose release];

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
@end
```